# Getting javascript error with a for loop even though it's working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check a series of check boxes depending on the results I get from a string. Since the values in this string are separated by commas I do the following:

```
var busLines = 'AB, CD, EF, GH, IJ, KL'
var temp = busLines.split(', ');
```

So now my array 'temp' should be the individual elements of my string:

```
temp[0] = 'AB'
temp[1] = 'CD'
temp[2] = 'EF'
and etc...
```

Each one of those values that are being returned in my array of 'temp' correspond with a check box with the same ID. So when I loop through and value 'AB' comes up, the check box id='AB' will get checked.

That is why I try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(temp[i]).checked = true;
}
```

When I test it out id does exactly what I want it to do, but it gives me the following error:

Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 530
Char: 9

I don't understand why I am getting an error when what I want it to do works. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's in `busLines`? What's in `temp[i]`? Do you have an element on your page that has an ID of `temp[i]`? Please add all relevant info.

Comment: Maybe you have fewer HTML elements than array elements?

Comment: That call to `new Array()` is not useful.  Just assign the result of the split directly. `var temp = busLines.split(', ');`

Comment: Alex you're right, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have an ID that wasn't found on the page. You should be coding this defensively anyway, by adding in null checks and such.

Try something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(temp[i]);

    if(checkBox) {
        checkBox.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @rshivers - why not fix the real problem here and either remove the bad item from the temp array or fix the missing item in the HTML.  You shouldn't have this error in the first place.  This just adds a bandaid to it rather than fix the actual source of the error.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00 about fixing the source of the error. However, this sort of coding practice should always be implemented.

Comment: Anything I can do to fix the source of my error is much appreciated, that's why I edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

That means one of your IDs doesn't exist (or possibly there's an extra "," at the end of your string. You should make sure all the IDs exist. If you just want to ignore the error, you can wrap your call to getElementById in a try/catch.

Comment: @jbabey - what's wrong with using a try/catch too handle expected or unexpected errors?

Comment: @jfriend00 the case of `document.getElementById` returning `null` is to be expected and handled properly by conditional checks. using exceptions and exception handlers for non-exceptional cases to control program flow is a bad practice in any language.

Comment: @jbabey - This particular example is a trivial case because error checking is only needed in one line of the code, but I've written code that would require 20 or 30 error checks to appropriately handle all possible errors from errors in unknown content, but one simple `try/catch` around the outer loop handled all of them much simpler and more foolproof.  I don't understand why exception handling in JS gets labeled as bad practice.  It can be very, very useful and more foolproof in some cases.

Comment: @jfriend00 handling exceptions is not a bad practice at all. using exception handling to deal with poorly written code is the bad practice.

Comment: @jbabey - by that yardstick, Jordan's answer is probably wrong too.  The real problem with this code is that there's either a bad value in the temp array or there's a missing value in the HTML.

Comment: I'm not an expert in javascript, so that's why I ask these questions here because obviously you guys know a heck of a lot more than I do. I agree with what bart s says, but I'm at a loss as far as correcting the issue. Jordan gave me a solution that, to me in my limited knowledge, resolved my issue. So what would be the solution, in terms of code, to make sure that I don't have an extra ', ' at the end when I split up the string busLines and assign it to my array temp?

Comment: @jbabey There's nothing any more wrong about using try/catch to ignore errors as using try/catch to handle errors. Ignoring is just a method of handling errors. Yes, there is a problem with the data (as I pointed out in my answer), and the OP should look into that first anyway.

Comment: @rshivers - As multiple people have asked here, you'd have to show us what's in the `busLines` variable and how the data gets in that variable for us to know how to fix the real issue.  Without seeing that data, we can't know if it's an empty element in the split array or a wrong element or something missing from your HTML.  It's probably one of the three.

Comment: I just edited my question so you can get a better look at what I'm trying to do. Like I said, since I don't understand everything that's going on sometimes it's not easy to explain my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is accessing one more item than really exists e.g. when busLines ends with ', '